# Whats the diff between setting top=0,bottom=0,left=0,right=0 OR width=100% , height=100%

Tags: apache-flex, properties, flex4, components, size

the child component can take all its parent width and height by setting its
properties

```
top=0,right=0,bottom=0,left=0
```

But same can be done by setting the child component properties

```
width=100%,height=100%
```

so whats the difference between these two approaches ?? plz give advantages/disadvantages if possible .thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same effect in a BasicLayout.  The only different might be in performance.  In other layouts like VerticalLayout and HorizontalLayout I don't think the constraints (top, right, etc) have any effect, but the percentage values do.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring GraphicElements with strokes is slightly different between using width/height and constraints.  This blog post explains in more detail: http://flexponential.com/2010/03/14/measuring-a-graphicelement-with-a-stroke-in-a-group/